# Certification - how will magento 2 release affect it?

Tags: certification

I am about to shortly sit my certification exam but am now seeing a lot of hype around magento 2.

Does anyone know how the release of Magento 2 will affect the current certificaiton?

Will it sill be valid?  Will it need updated/replaced etc?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was asked in the context of Magento 2 alpha and is no longer relevant. See: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/907/magento-2-questions-tagged-beta-alpha-pre-alpha-etc-quo-vadis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this type of question really doesn't belong here, both because it's Magento 2 related and also purely opinion based, I'm going to answer it anyway...

**Take the exam!** There most likely won't be a certification available for Magento 2 on release day, but there will certainly be one eventually. The existing exam will still hold plenty of validity. Besides, who better to replatform Magento 1.x merchants onto Magento 2.0 when it's released than those who have a 1.x cert and/or 2.x cert once it's out there?

The hype/activity on twitter you've seen over the past couple days is what happens when a select group of individuals (including myself) gather with Magento to help determine the architecture and product direction Magento 2 will take. You won't see an alpha release yet for quite some time.

Comment: Yes, I believe it takes 6 months to develop such an exam and get it approved for test taking by the certification facilities.

Comment: Not only should you take the cert for the reasons given, you also never know when certs will maintain some type of "grandfathering" so that when the new cert comes out, it may be easier to renew/retake.

Comment: 6 months after the first production release?

Comment: That is a question that I can say is not settled. Seeing as there is not yet a fully architected product not a release date, building a cert is not tops on the list. My guess (and req of Magento) is that this come after refreshing their Magento U courses, etc.

Comment: @Mark Shust is right about 6 months being a reasonable timeline. IIRC, it took roughly 4 months between the time I started working on the first certification and it having it's beta run at the Innovate conference. There was time spent by Magento before that planning for it, and afterwards a lot of time on logistics to get it rolled out. It's an undertaking, that's for certain, and I wouldn't expect it for at least 6 months after a production release...there may be more certainty as a release become imminent though. ;)

Comment: Another good point is that Magento 1.X won't go anywhere for years to come, and Magento 2.X is a huge change in architecture. You'll most likely want to be versed in both.