# Magento 2 - Questions of Exam

Tags: magento2, certification

I need reference questions about Magento 2 to get the Magento 2 certification.

Is there a list of questions for the Magento 2 exam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

**Status: April 2016**

---

There is no Magento 2 Developer Certification yet, it will probably come this year. There was an official statement somewhere that the certifications should be based on real world experience and just after the release nobody would have that.

However, there is a **Trained Partner** certification program, so if your company is taking part in this, [this article](https://firebearstudio.com/blog/how-to-pass-the-magento-2-certification.html) should help you. Quoting the most important part:

> The Magento 2 Trained Partner Program  requires two specialists to complete the **Fundamentals of Magento Development**, as well as one frontend developer to complete the **Core Principles for Theming in Magento 2** course

Also, if you want to prepare yourself for an upcoming Magento 2 Developer Certification, the Magento U courses mentioned above will probably cover most of it too:

- For Developer Certification: [Fundamentals of Magento 2 Development](https://magento.com/training/catalog/fundamentals-of-magento-2-development)
- For Frontend Certification: [Core Principles of Theming in Magento 2](https://magento.com/training/catalog/core-principles-theming-magento2)

---

The [current personal certifications](https://magento.com/training/catalog/certification) are based on Magento CE 1.9 / EE 1.14.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2.x certification is now still not available. Raising our own questions in a practical way on Magento 2 Make us more efficient for future certification releases ( M2.x ).

[Here official list of certification courses](https://magento.com/training/catalog/certification) to know more by clicking learn more about versions.

Ref : [Certification - how will magento 2 release affect it?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8959/certification-how-will-magento-2-release-affect-it)

Comment: what time was Magento 2.0 released ?

Comment: @MagentoOdoo.com  Check this link for more info on release dates.http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/release-notes/bk-release-notes.html